# Image Map dynamic resize in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, imagemap

I want to dynamically resize an image map. I only found a solution for jQuery (https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps)

How can I realize this in Angular?

Comment: hey did you found any solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/image-map-resizer
It works with javascript call :

**sample**

in HTML :

```
 <img src="...." width="100%"  usemap="#usaMap" (load)="imageResized();">
```

in TS :

```
declare function imageMapResize(): void;

@Component({...

})
...
imageResized() {
  imageMapResize(); // Javascript function in imageMapResizer.min.js 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer works, however, you have to download the **imageMapResizer.min.js** into the assets folder.

Then, you should import it in the **index.html** file like this:

```js
<script src="./assets/imageMapResizer.min.js"></script>
```

I thought that the file should be imported in the angular.json file, but it didn't work ... index.html did the trick for me.